# Using regex to filter strings by length

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate a input field with regex with this pattern `[A-Za-z]{,10}`
I want it to only find a match if 10 or less chars was sent in the input field, the problem I get is that it will match all words that is less then 10 chars.

Is there a way to say if there is more then 10 chars in the input field come back as false, or is it just better to do a `strlen` with php?

Comment: Note that: `{,10}` is an invalid quantifier. Although: `{10,}` means" _"match 10 or more times"_, the expression: `{,10}` does NOT mean _"match from zero to ten times"_. It actually means: _"match a left curly brace, a comma, the digit 1, the digit 0 and a right curly brace"_. To get the behavior you want, you need to specify the first digit like so: `{0,10}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important syntax mistake being made here by the OP and all the current regex answers: When using the curly brace quantifier with PHP (PCRE), you need to specify the first number. (i.e. The expression: `{,10}` is NOT a valid quantifier!) Although the comma and second number are optional, **the first number in a curly brace quantifier is required**. Thus the expression should be specified like so:

```php
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]{0,10}$/', $text))
    // Valid input
else
    // Invalid input
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to validate that it's alphabetic only, don't use `strlen()`.  Instead, put boundaries (`^$`) on your regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{,10}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just match `^[A-Za-z]{,10}$` it will check that the whole string is 10 or less.

Answer (score 0):

`^[A-Za-z]{,10}$`

`$@#$^&$a36#&$^` will pass your regexp because `a` is substring of it and `a` pass `[A-Za-z]{,10}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the length of the string, regex is heavy-handed and you should use `strlen` instead.